# Iterate item in array again after last item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have video list to play, I want to play videos again after last video 
  This is my component.ts where I iterate name of the videos

```
refreshVideoList() {
  this.fileService.getVideos().subscribe((res: any) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      setTimeout((item) => {
        if (item.status == 'Active') {
          this.file = item.filename.toString();
        }
      }, i * 20000, res[i]);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Is it angularJS or angular? +  purpose of `setTimeout()` function?

Comment: Sorry angular purpose of setTimeout() is play video in same div

Comment: Can you provide a sample stackblitz where I can have your code running?

Comment: I never used stackblitz before, so paste some code for you to observe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwscxt

Comment: **item** will be undefined, what is item representing here ?, Please add **res** json

Comment: I dont know about stackblitz, items are some of string values